# JSON in WP with GET/POST method (security problems)

Tags: javascript, json, security, wordpress, jquery-mobile

So I'm working on some mobile application that will represent WordPress page. 
Working it like web page, then spreading it to all mobile platforms using phonegap (mainly just taking webkit, moving all his functionalities, and putting that small webpage to applications) 
Web is written in jQuery/JavaScript/html/css.

I come to some security problems. All data on original WordPress site is secret, and only members can see stuff from there.
And I need to get data in JSON format. 
And there is my problem. :)

I can install (i did install) JSON api, and i can get every bit of data I want. But the problem is that anyone can (just type some "get" stuff in URL (for example: mysite.com/json/get_post/?id=1)).

I need to "secure" that data, and let it go only if the user who is asking for it is logged in.

What is the best solution?

I know there is a lot of security problems in this stuff. And only some encryption would be useful. But I need quick and easy solution that will at least make it harder than just typing url. :)

I found something about oAuth, but didn't really understand the way to use it. Any ideas? Any WordPress plugin? Anything?

Thank you. :)

Comment: You just need to do some authentication on the server side. Have PHP check to see whether the user is authenticated before spitting out that JSON.

Comment: yeah. But how? =) My PHP knowledge is really low. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is an [OWASP A4 - Insecure Direct Object Refernce](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References) vulnerability.  Encryption does not solve this problem and is by no means the right tool.   The problem is use access control.  The user needs to login to the wordpress install in order to gain this type of information.  Wordpress has a session system built in and you'll have to read up on their API documentation.

Comment: fair enough. shall give it a try. :)